# android application wont start

Tags: android

Im trying to debug my menu activity but it cant seem to display the output. The error msg on the screen says Savings Guider(my app name) has stopped working. If I click my app manually from the android menu, it says my app is not installed. However there are no errors in my codes. Anyone can help me?

My Menu Activity codes:

```
public class SavingsGuiderMenuActivity extends SavingsActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    ListView menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_Menu);
    String[] items = { getResources().getString(R.string.start),
            getResources().getString(R.string.about),
            getResources().getString(R.string.help) };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_item, items);
    menuList.setAdapter(adapt);
    menuList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {
            // Note: if the list was built "by hand" the id could be used.
            // As-is, though, each item has the same id
            TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked;
            String strText = textView.getText().toString();
            if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.start))) {
                // Launch the app Activity
                startActivity(new Intent(SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.this, SavingsGuiderAppActivity.class));
            } else if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.help))) {
                // Launch the Help Activity
                startActivity(new Intent(SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.this, SavingsGuiderHelpActivity.class));
            } else if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.about))) {
                // Launch the about Activity
                startActivity(new Intent(SavingsGuiderMenuActivity.this, SavingsGuiderAboutActivity.class));
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

}

My manifest:

```
  <application
    android:label="@string/splash"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/saving">
    <activity
        android:name=".SavingsGuiderMenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Logcat errors

```
07-22 03:18:24.712: E/ArrayAdapter(806): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12581)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:579)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:392)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12581)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4671)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12581)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4671)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12581)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12581)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4671)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2062)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12581)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1038)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2382)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
07-22 03:18:24.772: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  ... 33 more
```

Comment: look in the logcat and post the stacktrace from the exception that is force closing your application.

Comment: my logcat has a lot of errors and I saw most of them have something to do with the array adapter and also the linear layout,relative, etc. it is like as if my xml layout is the cause of my problems. is that possible?

Comment: could be, edit your question and post the logcat we'll be able to help you more.

Comment: Ive posted. I cant seem to understand this error = 07-22 03:18:24.712: E/ArrayAdapter(806): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView. Ive given all my textviews an ID already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No your xml is fine I think. If you're trying to create a menu to choose between activities, this is probably not the best way.

```
String classes[] = {"class_a","class_b","class_c"};
String class = classes[position]; Class ourClass=Class.forName("package_name"+class);
Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourClass);
startActivity(intent);
```

Try this in your onItemClicked() in try brackets.

Comment: String class = classes[position]; Class ourClass=Class.forName("package_name"+class); << I have errors marked on the 'String class' variable inc the one inside the forName brackets...

Comment: String class = classes[position];
Class ourClass = Class.forName("example.package.com" + class);
It works fine. Did you enclose it within try brackets with a catch clause?

Comment: it says String cannot be resolved to a variable when I mouseover it. I think eclipse read my String datatype as a variable..?

Comment: nvmd guys Ive solved it! Im not sure what was the problem exactly. I just retyped my codes and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You further used three of your classes in your code namely SavingsGuiderAppActivity.java, SavingsGuiderHelpActivity.java and SavingsGuiderAboutActivity.java. You need to register them in the manifest as well.
Your manifest should look like this:

```
<application
android:label="@string/splash"
android:debuggable="true"
android:icon="@drawable/saving">
<activity
    android:name=".SavingsGuiderMenuActivity"
    android:label="@string/splash">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".SavingsGuiderAppActivity"
    android:label="@string/splash">
<intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="ACTIVITY_A" />
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".SavingsGuiderHelpActivity"
    android:label="@string/splash">
<intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="ACTIVITY_B" />
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".SavingsGuiderAboutActivity"
    android:label="@string/splash">
<intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="ACTIVITY_C" />
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks @Adnan Zahid. Ive registered but my app is still 'not installed'. I dont know where the problem lies..

Comment: tried. is it because my xml layout has problems or something, thats why it says my app isnt installed?

Comment: Look at the console output below if you're using eclipse. Does it say app installed ... starting activity something? Do you have any red markers in your code?

Comment: Yes it did say all of them. weirdly, there are no red markers in my codes =\ Im guessing maybe its my xml layout but its unlikely...